# SQL split one column into two columns based on values and use columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table: `ProductionOrder`

---

```
Id     Ordernumber     Lotsize
1        Order1            50
2        Order 2           75
3        WO-order1         1
4        WO-order2         1
```

Table: `history`

---

```
Id          ProductionOrderID          Completed  
1            3                         1
2            3                         1
3            4                         1
4            4                         1
```

Table: `ProductionOrderDetail`

---

```
ID   ProductionOrderID     ProductionOrderDetailDefID   Content
1     1                    16                            50
2     1                    17                            7-1-2018
3     2                    16                            75
4     2                    17                            7-6-2018
```

Start of my code:

---

```
 Select p.ID, p.OrderNumber, 
     Case productionOrderDetailDefID
         Where(Select pd1.productionOrderDetailDefID where ProductionOrderDetialDefID = 16) then min(pd1.content)
 from ProductionOrder p
     Left join History h1 on  p.id = h1.productionOrderID
     Left Join ProductionOrderDetail pd1 on p.ID = ProductionOrderID
```

The result in trying to get is

```
Id      Ordernumber     Lotsize   Productionorder        Completed
1       Order1            50           WO-order1           2
2       Order 2           75           WO-order2           2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some further explanation of your intentions would be appreciated. In your `result` you seem to combine (`JOIN`) some records of your first table based on their `ordernumber`. Does the `history` table play a role in the `JOIN` process?

Comment: I think you are in the very beginning level of `SQL` so please do some study and research about it. Above you mentioned are objects which is called `table` not `database` please correct it. The requirement is also not so meaningful.

Comment: You need to explain in more details the logic of grouping and pivoting the data. Or you need to fix the issues with the current one. Otherwise, you will continue to get wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT ordernumber,lotsize,Ordernumber,count(Ordernumberid) 
       FROM productionorder inner join history on productionorder.id = history.Ordernumberid 
       GROUP BY Ordernumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of weird joins going on here. You should add this to a SQL fiddle so that we can see our work easier.

A link to SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Here is my first attempt

```
SELECT
        po.id
    ,   po.ordernumber
    ,   po.lotsize 
    ,   po2.productionorder 
    ,   SUM(h.completed) 
FROM productionorder as po 
INNER JOIN history as h 
    ON h.id = po.id 
INNER JOIN prodcuctionorder as po2 
    ON po2.ordernumberid = h.ordernumberid 
WHERE po.id NOT EXISTS IN ( SELECT ordernumberid FROM history ) 
GROUP BY 
        po.id 
    ,   po.ordernumber 
    ,   po.lotzise 
    ,   po2.productionorder
```

How far does that get you?